# Docker compose: npm ERR! missing script: build

Tags: node.js, docker

Hello I don't know where I am wrong when trying to use the docker compose with postgress

docker compose yml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: emasa
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    web:
      image: emasapg
      depends_on:
        - dbs
      ports:
        - "4000:4000"
```

dockerfile

```
FROM node as builder
WORKDIR usr/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build


FROM node
WORKDIR usr/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --production

COPY --from=builder /usr/app/dist ./dist

COPY ormconfig.docker.json ./ormconfig.json
COPY .env . 

expose 4000
CMD node dist/src/index.js
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "back-end",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Awesome project developed with TypeORM.",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.3",
    "@types/graphql": "^14.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^13.9.1",
    "ts-node": "8.6.2",
    "typescript": "3.3.3333"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.11.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "graphql": "^14.6.0",
    "pg": "^7.3.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "typeorm": "0.2.24"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node src/index.ts"
  }
}
```

err:

> npm ERR! missing script: build

my file structure:

[image]

the error starts on this line:

> line 6 : RUN npm run build

**Edit**: had forgotten to add the package.json to the question

Comment: it's basically complaining about missing the build script, it tries to run build script but itis missing , Can you please update the question and post your `packages.json`  file ?

Comment: @WaLid LamRaoui done bro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's basically complaining about missing the build script, it tries to run it,    but it is missing in your `package.json` !

i think you should try updating your `package.json` file and add a build script :

```
{
  "name": "back-end",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Awesome project developed with TypeORM.",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.3",
    "@types/graphql": "^14.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^13.9.1",
    "ts-node": "8.6.2",
    "typescript": "3.3.3333"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.11.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "graphql": "^14.6.0",
    "pg": "^7.3.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "typeorm": "0.2.24"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node src/index.ts",
    "build": ""  // your build script goes here, "tsc" should be fine
  }
}
```

Comment: hi brother thanks for help can helpme with this: Step 13/15 : COPY .env .
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder209795817/.env: no such file or directory

Comment: i got problem to copy this: COPY --from=builder /usr/app/dist ./dist

Comment: You get me confused bcoz of the second comment, what's the step that failed ? Step 13/15 means : `COPY .env .` and i assume it should fail , in this case i think you just need to create a `.env` file in the root directory of your project as it doesn't exist indeed

Comment: did this helped ?